# How to add new assignment in a sub-project of a Master Project Plan in MSP VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have written the following sample code to add a new assignment for the resource with id 1 to the current active task:

```
Sub testAddAssignment()
     ActiveCell.Task.Assignments.Add ResourceID:=1
End Sub
```

If I execute the code above for a standard (non master-plan) project file, then the code works fine.

However, if I execute the code above for a sub-project included in a Master Project Plan like the following
[image]

then I get the following error message:
[image]